# See which feature requests have been recently completed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Back when we used UserVoice, I liked to occasionally browse the Completed tab and see what changes were made and features were recently added to the site. While I do think that Meta is ten times better at enabling users to suggest, discuss, and vote on feature requests, one of the downsides is that we are missing that feature.

The closest you can come is browsing the [active tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed&sort=active&pagesize=15). For the most part this works, but as the posts aren't closed or locked in any way, any activity on the post (edit, new answer, etc) will toss it back to the top of the active queue even though the `status-completed` tab was added some time ago.

**edit:** I recently tried [Kip's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/see-which-feature-requests-have-been-recently-completed/6203#6203) and, at least on Apple Mail, it suffers from the same problem that the Active tab suffers from. Namely, activity causes the RSS item  to reappear with "UPDATED" in the title. Although it's possible to use another RSS reader with the capacity to ignore updates, I do think that an in-band solution is still preferable.

Comment: feature-request-request

Comment: i'd say tag it feature-requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is now a [community-maintained recent changes post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) with all recently implemented features of importance. This should suffice for major feature changes.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, maybe you could subscribe to the [status-completed RSS feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed)?

I know in Google Reader, if something shows up in the feed which has already been viewed, it doesn't show up as new.  This would ensure that, after initially marking everything as read, you don't see any more items, except those which were just tagged status-completed.  I don't know how other RSS aggregators work in this regard...

Comment: That could work, I'll give it a shot

Comment: The only downside is sometimes people make requests for something that already exists, and so the request is naturally marked 'status-completed'.  But that happened on UV, too.

Comment: If there is editing on the question, it will appear again.

Comment: @Brad i think that depends on your aggregator.  I know for sure that Google Reader doesn't mark something as new if its content changes.  If its link or ID changes, though, it thinks it is a separate post and shows it as new (so editing the title would have that effect).