# Monthly Summary of What's New

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, deployment

There have been a [few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26021/what-was-released-with-build-4983) [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/could-we-see-a-changelog-of-deployments) for a change log or release notes which I think would be great.

I understand that things are constantly changing, and if the team had to update us with every change, it would be a full time job.

That is why I propose a **Monthly Summary of Changes.**

The team could throw together a quick list of changes that have been implemented in the past month.  I would only be interested in changes to the functionality or look and feel of the site.

So, what do *you* think?

Of course the *monthly* could be replaced with *quarterly*, *bi-monthly* or whatever.  It would be nice to strike a balance between the users wanting to know what changes, and the team writing change notes.

**Edit:**
I know that I could search for feature requests or bugs that have recently been marked complete on meta.  However, there is no way for us to see what changes have been implemented if they didn't come from meta.

Comment: I think the SO blog fits into this discussion very well.

Comment: I've added a separate question to cover to [community tracked recent changes.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-changes-on-stackoverflow) This is because we should separate actual the tracking from your feature request.

Comment: @Jeff, I'm not sure why you removed the **`[feature-request]`** tag.  I still think this is a request.

Comment: @Jeff, I agree, this is a very popular feature request.

Comment: @lance I told Rebecca to keep it up to date. If she is not, then you should follow up with her. Thanks.

Comment: @jjn I told Rebecca to keep it up to date. If she is not, then you should follow up with her. Thanks.

Comment: {unnecessarily rude comment by me removed. [I apologize](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80128/sites-too-cold-ill-go-someplace-warm/80142#80142).}

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*Edit by Gnoupi: The content of this answer has moved to [a dedicated place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-changes-on-stackoverflow) for the community to update it, leaving this feature request to its first purpose.*

*Think about updating your feeds and favorites for notifications.*

And:

#### Look at that long list, when considering if this very feature request needs your upvote!

Comment: Dang you beat me to the bounty thing

Comment: I just realized.. there is a size limit on posts... pretty soon I bet this post will exceed it

Comment: @Earlz, I'd hope pretty soon this question either gets `status-declined` or `status-planned`. ;-)

Comment: Aha, `status-deferred` on [A better notification of significant modifications on the trilogy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/a-better-notification-of-significant-modifications-on-the-trilogy)

Comment: (As for maximum size: [36 paragraphs, 4403 words, 29849 bytes of Lorem Ipsum seems to be the maximum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/54948#54948))

Answer (score 6):

I believe it would be informative to see a summary of changes - but maybe quarterly depending on quantity of changes. I don't know how easy this would be. I would also think that in most cases, a summary of changes will likely list all changes.

Answer (score -18):

Is there any reason that ...

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed%20-retag-request&sort=newest

or

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed%20-retag-request&sort=active

... doesn't work for you?

Comment: That link shows recent posts that have been marked `status-completed`, not posts that have recently been marked `status-completed`. You could have completed an old request and that would be buried near the bottom. The active sort is better, but still not perfect. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6199/see-which-feature-requests-have-been-recently-completed

Comment: Are all Great New Things the result of a feature request or bug report then?

Comment: Also, this assumes that you only make changes that come from the community.  I'd also like to know what has been changed that didn't come from meta.

Comment: It's funny you could already predict that Jeff would answer with this :-P You're so predictable!

Comment: Those are helpful links btw.  They just don't fully accomplish what I am requesting.

Comment: A single post every month or so that I could subscribe to with RSS would be awesome

Comment: There is never pleasing you jjinguy :D

Comment: @Ólafur I can never get enough...

Comment: @Jeff: You often mark items [status-completed] when the suggestion in the question was *not* implemented, but rather rendered redundant or achieved in some other way. It is a very imperfect way of logging what has actually been implemented.

Comment: oh snap jeff got downvoted big..

Comment: Hate to say it, but I totally agree, this is total -1 ...

Comment: One problem nobody has mentioned so far is that the majority of the SO users never ever look at meta.