# Should there be a "check the blog" link above/below the "How to Ask" box on the Meta "Ask Question" page?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, asking-questions, blog

The stream of questions about the recent change to the bounty system has raised the idea of notifying users of changes - which Jeff is against.

So how about adding a "Check the blog" link to the Meta "Ask Question" page on the right above or below the "How to Ask" box you get while you're typing the question title?

[image]
<sub>(source: [free-online.co.uk](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/images/check-the-blog.png))</sub>

Would this be a non-invasive way of notifying people?

There are other questions [like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54622/would-highlighting-the-existence-of-the-blog-help-block-the-hordes-of-confused-qu) which mention the same problem, but don't really suggest an answer.

In response to devinb - The link should only be made active if there have been recent changes announced in the blog, there's no need to have it active all of the time. And to reiterate - it should only be here on Meta, it doesn't make sense to have it on any of the other sites.

Comment: I technically posted that question in order to provoke answers that *would* solve the problem. I suggested the FAQ or About pages, but putting it in the How To Ask in Meta actually would not be a bad idea.

Comment: @Grace - sorry.

Comment: Oy, oy, oy! No need to apologize for a good idea! I was just about to link this post in my question so that people can find it from there as well. However, if you'd like, you can post an answer over there with something along the lines of "I've proposed a solution to this problem over in this feature-request", and link your question here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be all that helpful. Mostly because the blog is only peripherally related to current changes.

That is, although the blog is always *about* StackOverflow, the front page doesn't always have notes about current changes. Sometimes it has notes about [new staff](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-hires-in-new-york/), [funny photos](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/workin-on-ur-problemz/), or [other](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/careers-now-more-awesomer/) [sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/) [entirely](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/).

The items are all *related* to StackOverflow, but not usually about *using* StackOverflow, which to my mind, specifically precludes it from the prominent place you are giving it.

We must consider the use case. A new user who tries to ask a question will see this link (Check The Blog!) and click it. From there, they will land [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/), which is currently about the Careers option. So suddenly, it looks like "blog" is just an internal advertisement. Even if it *happened to be* one of the blog posts that is about recent changes, it doesn't necessarily help a *new user*. If anything, it just confuses the issue. Why should new users care about recent changes?

Ultimately, this will only create confusion, and be easily overlooked.

Comment: You bring up some very wise points about new users. The majority of people who would probably be confused by feature changes and would post the hordes on Meta are probably the same class of users who have understood the site long enough to not pay any attention to the side bar.

Comment: Perhaps it should only be made active if there have been recent changes announced in the blog.

Comment: @ChrisF While this is an interesting option. It would break consistency. "This link is where you go to check recent changes, always, except when the link isn't there anymore." I'm currently creating a feature request of my own idea, please stand by.