# Is Careers broken?

Tags: support, jobs

What happend to [Careers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Careers) in the last few days? When I log in there are only links that are not specific to my account.
There is no link from my name (to the left of "logout", "stackoverflow", "about" and "faq") as there used to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not broken and there is in fact another specific link. Opening the link "file your cv" will show the same information as the link with the name used to do. (Candidate for inclusion into [Monthly Summary of What’s New](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new/47815#47815).)

Answer (score 3):

We've pushed out a substantial refresh which takes over for jobs.stackoverflow.com (and jobs.serverfault.com and jobs.joelonsoftware.com).

Blog post coming soon...do use Meta to tell us more.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem broken to me: since the update, I can't seem to browse CV's, the link on http://careers.stackoverflow.com does a redirect to the "My CV" page, and the button that used to be at the top for "Browse CVs" is gone.