# Flagging tags as interesting tags from multiple browser leads to weird behavior

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

Sorry for the weird title. I'll explain what happened.

I had a bunch of tabs opened in Chrome and added different tags as interesting in each of them. I expected the tags to accumulate so all of them appear in my list of interesting tags at the end. However, only the tags added in the most recent tab were there, everything added earlier was gone.

Comment: The title did make me do a double take :)

Comment: That would be not processsafe, not not threadsafe — Each tab in Chrome is a process.

Comment: Same with ignored tags, I assume?

Comment: I've definitely  noticed that favourites don't work perfectly.. e.g. I have the [Monthly Summary of What's New](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/monthly-summary-of-whats-new) question favourited, but it *never* shows up in my recent activity list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by the client and the server simply accepts whatever the client sends.