# Thousands of pages; no concise List of Features

Tags: discussion

This short list of searches, between them, turned up a whole lot of the same questions; no useful solution/answer to the question.

- Index of Features
- List of Features
- SO Features List
- Stack Overflow Things You Can Do Here
- Description of Tasks
- How To: A Brief Summary For Each Feature
- TL;But Durnit Useful

Am I correct in thinking that in the year and a bit since [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74368/why-are-so-many-features-hidden),
nothing has changed?

The general direction was, well if a user doesn't stumble onto what they need/want,
they can always ask!

Right. An hour plus looking for it (like an easter-egg hunt, seriously?) and another
half hour ploughing through a lot of search-returned questions and now I feel okay asking
"Where is the List of Features?"

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: That is all part of the fun. I remember when I found out how to downvote.. that was the best day of my life.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that visibility is a bit of a problem to the uninitiated, and that Meta (even in the FAQ tag) is a bit of a soup bowl.

Comment: @Daniel Nope sir, that was one of the dozen or more questions I went to and read. :)

Comment: @Robert Indeed, wandering but hopefully not vague.  Sure it is fun going adventuring looking for Functionality, but just as sketchy as putting an Index page of a 2,387 page dead-tree book at some point deep (or shallow!) in a book, it is somewhat weird that a fantastic resource like SO doesn't have a page or two, list of... things it is great at doing.  Marginal cost of electrons is pretty low, y'know... and I would rather have spent that time coding or walking along the seawall.  Maybe it is just a cultural thing.  Whatever.  Back to work.  Cheers!

Comment: Writing useful, short documentation that people will actually read is surprisingly difficult.

Comment: @Jim nice. Thanks. Next question I ask in here, gonna figure that out.  Bullets.  Who knew.

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly it is you are looking for. A list of lists?

Comment: @Jeff Email me and I'll get back to you presently with a < 2 pg. example.  Regards.